# Node.js Cluster to Process Data as Often As Possible

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, pm2

Bear with me as I'm completely newb to cluster and the documentation isn't clicking with me.

```
if (cluster.isMaster)
{
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++)
  {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  for (const file in files)
  {
    cluster.workers.send(file); //***
  }
}
else if (cluster.isWorker) 
{
  process.on("message", (msg) => 
  {
    //...Process data here...
  });
}
```

*** is the sort of thing I want. Something like cluster.workers.send(...) that sends a message to the workers and whoever is not busy will take the message. If all workers are busy, then the message will wait to be sent until there's a free worker.

Comment: node cluster will create multiple instance of your applications. if you want to allow only one cluster to perform one task, you can user it with redis and redlock npm module. using this module you can allow only one cluster to perform one task one time among multiple cluster.

Comment: I'll check out redis and redlock, but is there a way I can achieve this without adding an additional dependency? That would be preferable if possible with not too much boilerplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a database to manage the queue if you will have a large number of tasks and redis will be a good choice for this as [Vinay Pandya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2036977/vinay-pandya) suggests.

You want to prevent extra dependencies, you can use a queue array in the cluster master process and push/shift the tasks to/from that array. To determine the free node, you can maintain a 'nodes' object and have a feedback from the each node on finish its task to update it. Feedback can be done with [process.send](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_event_message).

Comment: Yes you are right, but i suggest you should use redis instead of memory object because if you restart your application all the object will be gone. so for that use Redis, Redis is so fast it's like cache memory.

Comment: Absolutely. Having a little dependency to a very good solution doesn't hurt :)

Comment: So I think I got what I expected without using redis via listeners and process.send as Bulent Vural suggested, however I've realized clustering uses much more memory than I'll be able to afford for my task. Do either of you know if clustering with Redis will save memory? Ideally if I have 10 gb of JSON I want to store this in memory as 10gb not 10gb x (# of forked processes) which I think is happening now. In other words, can all my processes share a single instance of Redis? Thanks very much.

Comment: "http://stackabuse.com/setting-up-a-node-js-cluster/" says something I found interesting, "To be clear, forking in Node is very different than a POISIX fork in that it doesn't actually clone the current process, but it does start up a new V8 instance." I think I'll open a separate question